# Generate dynamic file name list

Tags: perl

I started programming in perl few months back and this is my first question on stackoverflow.com. I hope I can get a solution.

So I want to copy some files from an ftp server. The file names are in this format:

```
abc_201149_cde_07_fgh_include_internal
```

In this example the numeric part gets changed on weekly basis, e.g. 201149 says year = 2011 and week = 49. Similarly, 07 says which version it is.

I have copied all the file names into one file called "sdk_link.txt" and I am reading each file name from this and then copying to my local PC:

```
use Net::FTP;
use File::Copy;
$Login = "<redacted>";
$Pwd = "<redacted>";
$ftpHost = "<redacted>";
$ftpFolder = "/daj/dhakj/ahdakl/abc_201206_def_05";
$ftp=Net::FTP->new($ftpHost,Timeout=>100);
if ($ftp) 
{
    print $ftp->message;
}
$ftp->login($Login,$Pwd);
print $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($ftpFolder);
print $ftp->message;
open FILE,"sdk_link.txt" or die $!;
while($test=<FILE>) 
{
    chomp($test);
    #Copy the file
    copy("$test","/testing"); 
}
$ftp->quit;
```

I want to run this script every week on Windows. How can I make the numeric part change so that the correct files get downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is to keep a template on file, and insert the correct numbers. For example:

```
echo abc_%s_cde_%s_fgh_include_internal | 
    perl -MPOSIX -nE 'say sprintf $_, strftime("%Y%U", localtime()), "07";'
```

Output:

```
abc_201207_cde_07_fgh_include_internal
```

So that if you'd have a file with templates, you can use `%s` to insert strings, and provide arguments either from your own list of arguments, or dynamically, as you prefer. E.g.:

```
my $year = "2011";
my $week = "49";
my $ver  = "07";  # Strings or numbers does not really matter

open my $fh, '<', "sdk_link.txt" or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    my $file = sprintf $_, $year, $week, $ver;
    copy($file, "/testing") or die "Copy failed for file $file: $!";
}
```

I am not so sure File::Copy::copy works as intended for remote files, but that's another question. I believe [Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aFTP)::get() might be what you want.

Comment: hi I have tried to add template in the file but i do not know where i am doing mistake please help me to resolve the prob :

Comment: @user I don't know what you are doing wrong either. Perhaps if you told me what you did, I could help you.

Comment: can any body look at in my prob which i have post above .

Comment: while (<$fh>) {
    my $file = sprintf $_, $year, $week, $ver;
    copy($file, "/testing") or die "Copy failed for file $file: $!";
} by doing this if i would print $file then o/p is mcl_${year}${week}_hw79u_${ver}_epoc32_include_internal.zip20114907 ia comming. But my expectation is mcl_201149_hw79u_07_epoc32_include_internal.zip.One more thing i would like to mentioned that i did not use any new module .

Comment: @user1202644 That's a new question. And also, I surely did not recommend you to use interpolated varaibles in your strings, now did I?

Comment: instead of mcl_${year}${week}_hw79u_${ver}_epoc32_include_internal.zip if i would use mcl_201202_hw79u_04_epoc32_include_internal.zip then also whaterver o/p is coming is not the desired one

Comment: @user1202644 Look up the documentation for `sprintf`, then look at my answer. I'm sure you'll figure it out.